# Maps to quotient rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

If $R$ is a ring, $\mathfrak{a}$ is an ideal of $R$ and $S=A[x,y,z,\dots]$ where $A$ is a commutative ring, then is there a ring $S^\prime$ such that there is a bijection:
$$\mathrm{Maps}(S,R/\mathfrak{a})\simeq\mathrm{Maps}(S^\prime,R)?$$
By maps I mean ring homomorphisms.

I know that if $\mathfrak{a}$ is the zero ideal then $S^\prime$ can be chosen to be $S$. But I have no idea on how to start when $\mathfrak{a}$ is a general ideal of $R$.

Comment: Is this homework? What do you have so far?

Comment: @JamesHines No, this is not homework. I am self studying abstract algebra and I do not understand how to prove this. I do not understand how to begin proving it, so I would be really happy with a walkthrough because ideals are very confusing for me.

Comment: People downvote questions when you don't tell us what you've tried

Comment: @columbus8myhw I do not even understand how to start

Comment: Then say so in the question.

Comment: @columbus8myhw OK! Done!

Comment: No, in general there is not.